# Using ImportHTML and Google sheets for web scrape

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to scrape stock quotes from web pages using Google sheets and ImportHTML (and its variants like ImportXML and ImportData). It works on some web pages but not others. An example of a web page I'm unable to import data from is https://www.barchart.com/stocks/performance/price-change/advances.

I used the following code:
 `=IMPORTHTML("https://www.barchart.com/stocks/performance/price-change/advances","table",0)`. Is there a way to download or scrape this data?

Comment: Checkout [tag:alphavantage]

Comment: Thanks. I did. It seems Alphavantage has a limit on free API calls.

Answer (score 2):

You have other options. You can write a simple script in any language for web scraping, using python or JS, or try the barchart API, its free.

https://www.barchart.com/ondemand/free-market-data-api

Comment: I was looking through the Barchart Addon for Google Sheets and couldn't find one. Is it available for Google sheets? Can I call this API in Google sheets? Is there a readily available script to scrape EOD stock data?

Answer (score 1):

Tl;Dr IMPORTHMTL, IMPORTXML and IMPORTDATA can't import data from the referred webpage because it requires JavaScript be enable on the web browser.

---

IMPORTHMTL, IMPORTXML and IMPORTDATA  are able to get data from the source code of a file on the web.

The first two requires that the HTML be well formed, they can't get data from dynamic pages.

Reference

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)

Comment: I read through the attached link. It was helpful. Guess the webpage(s) I'm trying to scrape is dynamic in nature and requires Javascript. 1) Is there something I can do/set in my web browser to scrape the data or is it server controlled? 2) Can I employ a script to scrape dynamic pages? 3) I tried to use ImportXML to access stock data on Yahoo Finance but these calls were taking too long and timed-out. In the end, I had an error rate of 40%. It was meaningless to continue with Yahoo Finance. Do you have other (free) data options? Google Finance doesn't work on some exchanges.