# I would like to pull a specific row of data from this website www.quickfs.net into a Google Sheet and I cannot figure it out

Tags: google-sheets, import, spreadsheet

I'm not sure if I should be using ImportXML instead of ImportHTML or what's going on, but I cannot get either function to work on this website. I've had zero trouble on these two sites: [www.finviz.com](http://www.finviz.com) & [www.yahoofinance.com](http://www.yahoofinance.com), but [www.quickfs.net](http://www.quickfs.net) is a whole other beast for me. I'm not sure if it's the way the data is structured, but I have found zero resources for accomplishing my task.

Here's what I have for the ImportHTML function: =index(IMPORTHTML(CONCATENATE("https://quickfs.net/company/",A1),"Table", 50)).

These images are in order and they show exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. Nothing super complex, I thought. Any help would be much appreciated.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwJZf.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQRdG.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o9Jg.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFJGt.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/82QGQ.png
[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CDE4.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ImportHTML and Google sheets for web scrape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62388353/using-importhtml-and-google-sheets-for-web-scrape)

Comment: How do you go about figuring out what the index number of the data is? I know how the function works, but I'm having issues defining the data's index or table number.

Comment: `https://www.quickfs.net/` site is being updated dynamically using JavaScript, which I can confirm that it is, as seen [here](https://imgur.com/a/wx5yPYt) where there's no site data being loaded when JS gets disabled on the browser. Thus, simple functions ImportXML/ImportHTML isn't going to work on `quickfs.net` unfortunately as answered by a community from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62393289/15384825). Last thing that you can do is to use QuickFS [API](https://quickfs.net/features/public-api) to retrieve data from them.